# Sql Joins - Separating a field into two based on Id

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say we have a table:

```
ID  |  ItemId  |  Value  |
1   |   201    |  Green  |
2   |   301    |  Wood   |
2   |   201    |  Red    |
4   |   201    |  Green  |
1   |   301    |  Iron   |
```

So {ItemId:Type} -> {201:Color}, {301:Material}

Is there a way to generate the following result set?

```
ID |  Color  | Material  |
1  |  Green  | Iron      |
2  |  Red    | Wood      |
4  |  Green  | (null)    |
```

So depending on the `ItemId`, put the `Value` in Column 1 or 2.

Comment: Look up "crosstab" or "pivot".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate a pivot by using `CASE...WHEN` to selectively identify the result columns. You'll need to combine this with an aggregate (which will strip out the NULLs), and finally `GROUP BY` to compress the rows:

```
SELECT ID, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN ItemId = 201 THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS Color,
       MIN(CASE WHEN ItemId = 301 THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS Material
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/96faf/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` to grab the `Value`s according to the `ItemId` value and then `group by` `ID` to aggregate two rows with the same `ID` in one, while using `max` (or other aggregate function) to exclude `null` values :

```
select ID
     , max(case when ItemId = 201 then Value end) as Color
     , max(case when ItemId = 301 then Value end) as Material
from tbl
group by ID
```